# Nonhomogeneous Poisson Process Intensity Function

Tags: probability

A shop is open from 10am to 6pm. Customers arrive in the shop according to a nonhomogeneous Poisson process with an intensity function, which equals zero at opening, 4 customers per hour at noon, 6 customers per hour at 2pm, 2 customers per hour at 4pm, and zero at closing; between any two consequent afore-mentioned times, it is linear.

a) Find the distribution of the number of customers on a given day.

I'm not sure how to begin to write the rate function so that I can find the distribution.

Comment: Can you write (or draw) the rate function $\lambda(t)$ as a function of $t \in [0, 8]$, where $t=0$ corresponds to $10$am and $t=8$ corresponds to 6pm?

Comment: @Michael I don't see how you can do this since the rate function increases and then decreases.

Comment: I do not understand your above comment.  For an inhomogeneous Poisson process, the number of arrivals over an interval $[t_1, t_1+T]$ has a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\mu = \int_{t_1}^{t_1+T} \lambda(t)dt$.  A homogeneous Poisson process is a special case with $\lambda(t) = \lambda$ for all $t$, so $\mu = \int_{t_1}^{t_1+T} \lambda dt = \lambda T$.